# Highlight comment in Notepad++ after langs.xml alteration

Tags: notepad++, mysql, sql, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to fit Notepad++'s highlighting to my needs. Using MySQL most of the highlighting work is ok with the "SQL" setting under languages.

I now want Notepad++ to highlight single-line comments correctly (starting with `#`). I already changed the langs.xml and commenting lines with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> works, it puts a `#` in front of the line. But the line does not get highlighted! Instead it highlights the old version (lines starting with `--`). Is there an option I overlooked?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this, but anyway I'd avoid the hassle and create a custom language, copy over the SQL-settings and change my comments / colors / etc.

Comment: Thx for the advice. After some struggling I exactly did what you suggested, a custom language works ok for me now.